# Wordpress Calendar Plugin functionality

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, calendar

I have a client who needs a calendar for his wordpress website. I'm currently using Spider Event Calendar but the client has decided he needs more functionality than what is already included. I'm not sure if it's possible to add this functionality using javascript or php, I'd appreciate any insight or feedback. If there is a plugin out there that can do all of this, I'd be open to use it, but I've checked a good amount and they don't do exactly what we need.

The client wants :

- A calendar to display on the page with events that are already booked, there are three categories (All Day, Day Only, Night Only) [Spider Does This]
- Multiple calendars (10 total) [Spider does this]
- To be able to highlight the days clicked on (selected)
- Have the quantity change on the product page (woocommerce) based on the number of days clicked (e.g. If three days are selected, change the quantity to 3)
- Have the "Dates Selected" display on the checkout page (woocommerce)
- Blackout certain days based on the product selected. (weekend rates blackout weekdays, weekday rates  blackout weekend days.)

I'm not sure what code to include (if any) here to receive help as I'm mainly looking for if it is possible to add javascript or php functions to the Spider Event Calendar plugin. The client prefers this calendar's UI to add events.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/booking-calendar/                         https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-calendar-registration-booking-by-events-plus/

Comment: Booking Calendar doesn't allow multiple categories that I saw; I need to be able to have three different categories displayed. The Events Calendar isn't exactly what we're looking for either. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this calendar bookly plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/